# Null or false value in grails

Tags: grails

I have a domain class in which one of its fields is of type Boolean. When I retrieve it, how can I differentiate whether it's set to false or it's null ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(field == null)` will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example that demonstrates how to test for all 3 possible values of a Boolean

```
class Person {

  Boolean isMale = false
  Boolean isFemale = true

  Boolean isAdult = null
}

def p = new Person()

assert !p.isMale
assert p.isFemale
assert p.isAdult == null
```

You can run this code in the [Groovy console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) to verify the expected behaviour